# Kali Error while installing any package

Tags: software-installation, kali-linux, upgrade, mutter

I had recently installed kali from parrot.

After Successful installation. I run

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt upgrade
```

Now I am unable to install any package. It shows me error:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 gsettings-desktop-schemas : Breaks: mutter (< 3.31.4) but 3.30.2-7 is to be installed
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
```

When I try to run `sudo apt full-upgrade`, Another error:

```
 libc6-dev : Breaks: libgcc-8-dev (< 8.4.0-2~) but 8.3.0-6 is to be installed
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
```

This is my /etc/apt/sources.list:

```
http://http.kali.org/kali kali-last-snapshot main non-free contrib
```

And, ''apt-cache policy mutter'':

```
mutter:
  Installed: 3.30.2-7
  Candidate: 3.36.4-1
  Version table:
     3.36.4-1 500
        500 http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling/main amd64 Packages
 *** 3.30.2-7 100
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

Please Help.
Is anything extra I had to Post?

Answer (score 2):

I encountered the same problem and solved it by

- going to `/var/lib/dpkg/status`
- clearing the contents (these are dependencies in that file)
- running

  ```
  apt update && apt install -f
  ```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to the site. Please don't post [screenshots of console output](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4086/psa-please-dont-post-images-of-text). They are often difficult to read, and the content will not be accessible to google search results. Instead, paste it into the question using code formatting.

Comment: Images of text are also not readable by blind people.

Answer (score 0):

1. Open the log file in `/var/log/apt/term.log` in a text editor.
2. Scroll down to the most recent log entries near the end of term.log.
3. Locate any "broken" packages and remove them with `sudo apt remove package-name`.

   You can get a list of *actual* held packages with:

   ```
   dpkg --get-selections | grep hold
   ```
4. Try to run `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade` again.
5. Remove packages that were automatically installed to satisfy dependencies for other packages and are now no longer needed as dependencies changed or the package(s) needing them were removed in the meantime.

   ```
   sudo apt autoremove
   ```

Answer (score -3):

```
sudo apt install gcc-8-base mutter libmpx2
```

Comment: Welcome to the site. Would you mind adding some explanation on why simply installing `mutter` and `gcc-8` would resolve the OPs problem, although there is an indication of version conflicts?